# Can i travel to Malta with my UN 1951 Travel document issued by United Kingdom?

Tags: visa-free-entry, refugees, uk-residents, malta

Can i travel to Malta without a visa with my 1951 UN convention travel document issued by united kingdom?

Comment: Although you’d be travelling on a RTD, to answer we still need to know your citizenship  https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/MT However I think the answer is *no* https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list

Comment: @Traveler it is not necessary to know the applicant's citizenship to answer the question.  Citizenship is generally irrelevant for refugee travel, and this is no exception.  See my answer.

Comment: @phoog Using IATA or Timatic to search for an answer requires nationality details.

Answer (score 10):

The Maltese High Commission in London has this to say on [its website](https://foreign.gov.mt/missions/hc-london/services/):

> Important Note:
>
> In view that the UK is not a Schengen Member State and it is now longer in the EU, Malta did not apply to the derogation in article 6(2) of the EU Visa Regulation, which would exempt Refugees holding a Convention Document issued by the UK Authorities, from the requirement of a visa to enter Malta. Therefore, anyone with this kind of document has to apply for a Visa before coming to Malta.